# If $X\in\mathcal{L}_P^1$ does then the variance exist?

Tags: probability-theory

At the moment I am wondering about the following exercise:

> > Let $X\in\mathcal{L}_P^1$, show that $\mathbb{V}(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.

It's clear how to show that, that's not my point.

I am wondering, because if $X\in\mathcal{L}_P^1$, does then the variance exist at all? Isn't it necessary that $X\in\mathcal{L}_P^2$ for that?

Comment: The variance exists in $[0,\infty]$. You may have $E(X^2)=\infty$, but since $E(X)^2$ is a real number the formula for $\mathbb V(X)$ makes sense.

Comment: If I would have met this exercise then your thoughts would have been mine as well. If $X\in\mathcal{L}_{P}^{n}$ stands for $\int\left|X\left(\omega\right)\right|^{n}P\left(d\omega\right)<\infty$
then $X\in\mathcal{L}_{P}^{1}$ does not garantee the existence of
the variance of $X$. Unless you accept that it can be infinite.

Comment: @Etienne Ok, but why can't the Variance not be negative here?

Comment: Because of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (which holds for any nonmegative measurable functions) : $\vert E(X)\vert\leq E(\vert X\vert)=E(\vert X\vert\times 1)\leq E(X^2)^{1/2}\times E(1)^{1/2}$.

Comment: $E(X)<\infty$ since $X$ is summable. @Etienne: Cauchy-Schwarz is useful if you know that $X$ is square summable, which isn't the case here.

Comment: But it holds even if $X$ is not square summable...

Comment: @Erienne: If $X$ is not square summable, does the inequality $\vert E(X) \vert \leq E(X^2)$ have any interesting implications? It appears to me that the RHS is $= +\infty$ in this case.

Comment: @Roland. Of course it is not interesting! I was just answering the question "why can't the variance be negative?".

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. There are functions which are absolutely summable on $[0,1]$, but not square summable, for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Thus, the second moment does not need to exist for general $\mathcal{L}_P^1$-functions. See the comment of Etienne how to resolve this issue.